# IOS tableviews working with dictionaries as models

Tags: objective-c, ios5

i am starting to think through an example program i want to try. the premis is simple in that it lists me a large list of names with their gender.

for now i started to have a Person Class which has name and gender as properties. after that i build up a dictionary with the alphabetic letters as keys and an array of persons underneath each other. that works fine as in the table methods i can easily get the persons for each alphabet letter.

now i want to implement that i can switch of male or female.

the problem i'm running into is that all tableview controller methods would suddenly get much more complex. as an instance the numberOfRowsInSection method. before i just got the array for the letter key and returned the count. now i would have to parse through everything and count up the male Persons or female.

i feel like there is maybe a better way to approach this. but i'm not certain.

any ideas ? thanks in advance

Comment: You could create three arrays: one with all names, and one each for the genders.  Then, based on a BOOL value (perhaps connected to a button), decide which one to load into a fourth array-- the one you actually parse.  After you load the fourth array, simply reload the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

You either have to do it dynamically as you suggest which could become really slow if there are a lot of people in the list.

The other approach is to separate things into 3 arrays: one that contains everyone, one that contains males, and one that contains females.

Then you have a pointer that references one of the 3 arrays and you change this pointer when the user changes their preferences.